# form_tag renders in show but not index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've set up a custom action within my controller to "Favorite/Unfavorite" recipes. I've played around and found that the following code works in my show.html.erb to display/ use the favorite/ unfavorite button.

```
<% if current_user.present? && current_user.recipes.exists?(@recipe.id) %>
    <%= form_tag(controller: "recipes", action: "unfavorite", method: "post") do %>
        <%= submit_tag "Unfavorite"%>
      <% end %>
<% elsif current_user.present? %>
  <%= form_tag(controller: "recipes", action: "favorite", method: "post") do %>
      <%= submit_tag "Favorite"%>
      <% end %>
<% else %>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to add this action to my index.html.erb so that as you look at the list you can just favorite the recipe from there and I get the following error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Recipes#index
No route matches {:action=>"unfavorite", :controller=>"recipes", :method=>"post"}

   <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', recipe, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
          <td><% if current_user.recipes.exists?(recipe.id) %>
                  <%= form_tag(controller: "recipes", action: "unfavorite", method: "post") do %>
                      <%= submit_tag "Unfavorite"%>
                  <% end %>
              <% else %>
```

My index.html.erb code is as follows:

```
  <tbody>
    <% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to recipe.title, recipe %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Source', recipe.url%></td>
        <td><%= recipe.description %></td>
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_recipe_path(recipe) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', recipe, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
          <td><% if current_user.recipes.exists?(recipe.id) %>
                  <%= form_tag(controller: "recipes", action: "unfavorite", method: "post") do %>
                      <%= submit_tag "Unfavorite"%>
                  <% end %>
              <% else %>
                <%= form_tag(controller: "recipes", action: "favorite", method: "post") do %>
                    <%= submit_tag "Favorite"%>
                  <% end %>
              <% end %>
          </td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Why does this work in the show.html.erb but not in the index.html.erb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the recipe `id` to the form

```
<%= form_tag(controller: "recipes", action: "unfavorite", id: recipe.id, method: "post") do %>
```